I want to make a transparent block using Blender Python in Blender 4.3
I coded several animations of transparent blocks (here shown solving a 3D puzzle) successfully in previous versions of Blender, such as 2.8.
I cannot get the Blender 4.2.1 version of bpy to produce these clear blocks.  I have followed Ron Jenson's 2020 answer but it no longer works in Blender 4.2.1.  The blocks are speckled every time.
Short answer:  it was not the code but the values in the right-hand panes Settings, Scene and Render.
Step by step I have discovered what needs fixing:  increase sampling, limit max bounces, use not EEVEE but CYCLES over CUDA, select denoise option.  I also upgraded to Blender 4.3.

Its not entirely clear where you intend to use python in this. Do you have a script you're working on that isn't working? Do you have error Tracebacks you can paste from the System Console? All this info would help get your question answered.

do you have any overlapping geometry that could cause z-fighting?

@Jakemoyo there are no errors.  The code that used to work is on my Github page https://github.com/narratorjay/j3-j/blob/main/lunar.txt.  Both render engines, CYCLES and EEVEE, produce the same results.

@Lauloque the overlapping geometry is that the acrylic block plunges into the lunar terrain.

Please do not edit the title with "FIXED" or "Solved", instead provide an answer even if it's your own question.

My apologies, I answered my own question but not in the correct manner.
Short answer: it was not the code but the values in the right-hand panes Settings, Scene and Render.
Step by step I have discovered what needs fixing: increase sampling, limit max bounces, use not EEVEE but CYCLES over CUDA, select denoise option. I also upgraded to Blender 4.3.

